Animate cell color in tabularray (Beamer)
I want to show entries of a table I made with tabularray in beamer.
The code looks like this:
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
           
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
        
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{table}[h]
              \begin{booktabs}{
                colspec=ccccccccccccccc,
                cell{1-4}{2} = {cmd=\only<2->},      
                cell{1-4}{3} = {cmd=\only<3->},         
                cell{1-4}{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} = {cmd=\only<4>},        
        
                cell{1-4}{4,5,8,9} = {cmd={\only<5>{fg=gray5}}}, %this doesn't work
                }
                \toprule
                \textbf{A}    & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $\dots$ \\
                \textbf{A}  & H & H & C & H & C & H & C & C & C & C & H & $\dots$ \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{B}    & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $\dots$ \\
                \textbf{B}  & H & H & H & C & C & H & H & H & C & C & H & $\dots$ \\
                \bottomrule
                    \end{booktabs}
              \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

The issue is with the code  cell{1-4}{4,5,8,9} = {cmd={\only<5>{fg=gray5}}}: the intention is to color all these cells with grey on slide 5 only.

Please always include a compilable test document in your questions.

The code does not compile. Please test it before posting.

You can use \color<5>{gray} to change the foreground colour on a particular overlay:
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
      \begin{tblr}{
        cells={wd=0.3cm,halign=c},
        cell{1-4}{2} = {cmd=\only<2->},      
        cell{1-4}{3} = {cmd=\only<3->},         
        cell{1-4}{6,7,10,11,12} = {cmd=\only<4->},        
        cell{1-4}{4,5,8,9} = {cmd={\color<5>{lightgray}\only<4->}},
        }
        \toprule
        \textbf{A}    & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $\dots$ \\
        \textbf{A}  & H & H & C & H & C & H & C & C & C & C & H & $\dots$ \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{B}    & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $\dots$ \\
        \textbf{B}  & H & H & H & C & C & H & H & H & C & C & H & $\dots$ \\
        \bottomrule
            \end{tblr}
      \end{frame}
\end{document}



Thank you! Is \color a tabularray feature?

@forgetfuled No is isn't from tabularray, it is just the normal color macro from package like color or xcolor (beamer automatically loads the package)

ok bro actually  the behaviour isn't completely correct: i want the number to appear in one slide (in black) and on the next one they have to turn grey. What am i missing?

@forgetfuled See my updated answer

Sorry to disturb you again, how can i change the color of the grey cells to red in the next slide?

@forgetfuled If you have a new question, please ask a new question
